# Return a variable of type assigned in parameters?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, types

I'm trying to create a class like Windows Form, which will have multiple new features. It's simply going to be a "better" version of `Form`, making my work easier on this exact program. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class SuperForm : Form
{
    protected abstract void OnSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public SuperForm()
    {
        this.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }
}
```

Not much, it only makes sure every Form will have to define `OnSizeChanged` which will be called automatically when size changes, but there's going to be more.

What I need next is a method which takes a class/type as it's parameter and initializes a new object of that type, automatically adds it to `Controls` and then returns the object. Here's an example code (not working) on how I would like it to be like:

```
public cls NewControl(ClassType cls) // This obviously doesn't work.
// I need it to return an object of type "cls" parameter.
{
    cls newControl = new cls();
    this.Controls.Add(newControl);
    return newControl;
}
```

I know `ClassType` is not a valid type, that's why I need help.

And then I could basically call it like this:

```
Button b = this.NewControl(Button);
```

Which would return a new button and also add it to `this.Controls`. I might eventually need to do more of these common tasks when a control is initialized, so that's why I'd like to have it in it's own method.

Is this possible in C#? If not, are there any workarounds? One way would be to define a method for each class inheriting from `Control` like this:

```
public Button NewControl(Button b);
public TextBox NewControl(TextBox tb);
public ListBox NewControl(ListBox lb);
```

But it doesn't seem like a valid option to me.

Comment: How is OnSizeChanged better than overriding onresize?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Didn't know that one existed! `OnResize` seems to require me to call `base.OnResize()` first, but I guess it's not that big of a deal =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make a generic method, with a couple of constraints on the type parameter:

```
public T CreateAndAdd<T>() where T : Control, new()
{
    T newControl = new T();
    Controls.Add(newControl);
    return newControl;
}
```

Here the `T : Control` constraint makes sure that you're creating a control, so that you'll be able to use `Controls.Add`. The `T : new()` constraint makes sure the type argument has a public parameterless constructor, so that you can call `new T()`.

To create a TextBox, for example, you would call the function like this:

```
var tb = CreateAndAdd<TextBox>()
```

(I've renamed the method for what I believe to be clarity, btw.)

Comment: beat me by a few seconds :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks =) I'm kinda new to C#, it's nice to have you guys here to help!